# Gather turns my dates into unrecognisable format

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to gather a couple columns of dates so that its easier for it to be choices in shiny. However, when I gather dates, it turns into for example, 2020/12/14 to 128284 format. I have tried as.Date, as.character, I have tried lubridating but it doesn't work. (I have been gathering in a separate script besides shiny). Please see my code when gathering.

Here is my data

[before gather](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sc8i.png)

```
df<-df%>%gather(key="date.type", value="dates",
                     date.1, date.2, date.3, date.4)
```

This turns it to something like this;
[after gather](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgdVb.png)

This becomes a problem when I am trying to find difference between two dates in Shiny(I have been using difftime).

The error I get in shiny is:

```
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I am also thinking of not gathering at all, but allowing the user to choose the from date column and to date column in the UI, but I am not sure how to then find the difference in days between the from and to dates in the server.

```
mutate(theduration=difftime(input$to,input$from,units="days")
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide example data and code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Instead of sharing pictures of your data, please share copy/pasteable structure. `dput()` is very useful for this - use `dput(df[1:10, 1:5])` to share the first 10 rows and first 5 columns - choose a different subset if necessary. `dput()` will be copy/pasteable and will include the important class and structure information.

Comment: `gather` is not changing your date values without some other unexpected element in your data.  try this to see for yourself: `date_1 <- c("2020/01/08", "2020/01/09");
date_2 <- c("2020/02/08", "2020/02/09");
df <- data.frame(date_1, date_2);
df %>% gather(key = 'date.type', value = 'dates')`

Comment: I can see that it is not the gather, but I don't what else it could be, it completely the changes the format. Do you think its because I have lubridated it using df$date.1<-dmy(df$date.1)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had this problem when using gather to make a dataset. When you get those 5 digit time character blocks, try this:

```
mutate(time=as.Date(as.numeric(time),origin="1899-12-30"))
```

Apparently, that that 5 digit number is days since the origin date. It's a MS thing. Good Luck!